# Find a missing number in a sequence using .reduce

Tags: javascript

```
var o = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8]

var res = o.reduce(function(x,y){

   return !((y-x)===1)?y-1:'Nothing'

})
console.log(res)//7
```

Output should be 4, want to know if it is possible using reduce or functionally (Not through loops)? it only works if the missing value is before the last value of an array.

Comment: why output should be 4?

Comment: Because that is the missing number in this array, if you iterate it by one till 8

Comment: `reduce` goes through all elements; it doesn’t stop. If you return `"Nothing"`, eventually the subtraction is going to be `"Nothing" - x`, where `x` is a number. Try it with `find` instead.

Comment: _“It only works if the missing value is before the last value of an array.”_ — That’s like saying that a broken clock shows the correct time only twice a day.

Comment: @Xufox I used reduce because i thought to get a single value from an array it is useful, i didn't try find i have to check.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a start value and check the previous element and the actual element.

```js
var o = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    res = o.reduce(function(r, a, i, aa) {
        return !i || r !== undefined || aa[i - 1] + 1 === a ? r : aa[i - 1] + 1;
    }, undefined);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: That is freaking genius!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` to compute the actual sum of all elements and then subtract it from the target sum (`n(a0+an)/2`). This gives you the missing number.

```js
var o = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8];

var len = o.length;
var sum = (len + 1) * (o[0] + o[len - 1]) / 2;
var res = sum  - o.reduce((x,y) => x + y);

console.log(res);
```

Note that this works with any starting value and any step, e.g. for `[3,5,7,11]` it will correctly print `9`. The only requirement is that `o` should be an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Clever and elegant! I like it!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `reduce` you could use `find`, which will not look any further once it finds a missing value:

```js
const o = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8];
const res = o.find( (x,i) => o[i+1]-x > 1 ) + 1;
console.log(res)//4
```

Comment: @Kinduser For me, the question sounds like an example of [a car with square wheels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254341/4642212)… it may be possible to do this with `reduce`, but that doesn’t mean that there aren’t any better ways to do this.

Comment: This answer is absolutely amazing. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using `Array.reduce` and the ES6 arrow function for brevity.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const result = array.reduce((result, x) => x > result ? result : x + 1, 1)
console.log(result); // 4
```

---

With a little refactoring, we can start to make the solution more generic.

```js
const sequence = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const result = sequence.reduce(missingLinkReducer, sequence[0])

function missingLinkReducer(expected, actual) {
  return expected === actual ? nextValue(expected) : expected;
}

function nextValue(value) {
  return value + 1;
}

console.log(result);
```

---

Going a little bit further, we can make it so that different functions can be plugged in for calculating the next value.

```js
const sequence = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const result = sequence.reduce(createMissingLinkReducer(increment), sequence[0]);
console.log(result + ' is missing from ' + sequence);


const sequenceB = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 64, 128];
const resultB = sequenceB.reduce(createMissingLinkReducer(double), sequenceB[0]);
console.log(resultB + ' is missing from ' + sequenceB);


function createMissingLinkReducer(nextValue) {
  return function missingLinkReducer(expected, actual) {
    return expected === actual ? nextValue(expected) : expected;
  }
}

function increment(value) {
  return value + 1;
}

function double(value) {
  return value * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to generalize these jobs. So you should provide a series descriptor function for the algorithm to find which item is missing in the series. Let's do it;

```js
function findMissingItem(a,s){
  return s(a[a.findIndex((f,i,a) => i ? f !== s(a[i-1]) : false)-1]);
}
var data1 = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8],
    data2 = [1,4,9,16,36,49,64,81],
  series1 = n => n+1,
  series2 = n => Math.pow(Math.sqrt(n)+1,2);
     res1 = findMissingItem(data1,series1),
     res2 = findMissingItem(data2,series2);
console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use every for this, below will work for any sequence interval you specify - it will return -1 if all elements are in sequence, or the element that doesn't fit:

```js
var o = [1, 4, 7, 10, 11]
var seqInterval = 3;

function getMissing(arr, interval) {
  var hit = -1;
  var res = arr.every(function(e, i) {
    hit = i === 0 ? hit : ((e - interval) === arr[i - 1] ? -1 : e);
    return hit === -1;
  });
  return hit;
}

console.log(getMissing(o, seqInterval));

var o1 = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8];
var seqInterval1 = 1;
console.log(getMissing(o1, seqInterval1));
```